# How to compile hlsl shader file in Visual Studio C# project

Tags: c#, shader, hlsl, sharpdx

I would like to compile a hlsl shader file in my C# project in Visual Studio 2015. With a C++ project I immediately get the correct properties if I add an hlsl file like the picture below:

[image: HLSL build properties in C++]

However when I want to do this in my C# project (with SharpDX) I do not get such options and thus can't compile to an CSO file for my project.

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's now a NuGet package, [Microsoft.HLSL.CSharpVB](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.HLSL.CSharpVB/), that adds support for HLSL shader properties to C# and VB projects:

> This package installs MSBuild support for HLSL compilation in C# and VB projects.
>
> Please reload your project or restart Visual Studio for the new shader Build Actions to appear in the properties window.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this directly in a C# project, as the *Visual Studio* **HLSL** compilation built-in integration is only working and accessible from a **C++** project.

Though you could put an empty C++ project in the same solution, and then add and configure your HLSL files from there, and then reference generated cso files from your C# project as content (and add a project dependency from C# -> C++ project)... With some MSBuild trickery, you could also copy the generated content automatically into your C# project.

Comment: This is indeed a nice workaround. Setting the output object file name of the HLSL files to $(SolutionDir)<main project name>\%(Filename).cso. And then adding the cso file as a content file to the main project with the 'copy always' or 'copy if newer' did the trick.